# Flexslider - possible to control via hover instead of click?

Tags: hover, flexslider

I am using flexslider with manual controls, and it's working properly. But instead of clicking the controls, I need them to change the slide when you **hover** over the controls. Is this possible? I looked at the js file and can't find a click function to change.

Here is the flexslider js:
https://raw.github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/master/jquery.flexslider.js

And this is my code:

```js
$(window).load(function(){
    $('.flexslider').flexslider({
     animation: "slide",
     directionNav: true,
     controlsContainer: "header#site",
     manualControls: ".nav1 li"
    });
});
```

And the HTML is (simplified) this:

```html
<header id="site">
<ul class="nav1">
<li>Link 1</li>
<li>Link 2</li>
<li>Link 3</li>
</ul>

<div class="flexslider">
<ul class="slides">
<li>Image 1</li>
<li>Image 2</li>
<li>Image 3</li>
</ul>
</div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would like an answer to this issue as well. Found a way to trigger it with the hover alone, but I need to use the click function as well, so now I am getting some combative js. Here is what I have working that allows for hover AND click to work to move the slides, but I want to just replace the click with the hover altogether.

```
    start: function(slider){

            jQuery('.custom-pagination li').mouseover(function(){
                 var activeSlide = 'false';
                 if (jQuery(this).hasClass('flex-active')){  
                    activeSlide = 'true';                       
                 }
                 if (activeSlide == 'false'){
                  jQuery(this).trigger("click"); 
                 }
             });      
        }
```

Comment: Basically, what I want my slider to do is something like this :  http://www.tabletmag.com/ - where when you hover over the pagination, it switches the slides, but if you click on the pagination, it goes to the article. Any ideas?

Comment: Just coming back to mark this as the correct answer since you were able to solve the hover issue. Hope you found an answer to your issue as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

In jquery.flexslider.js, you just have to change at line 21:

```
eventType = "click touchend MSPointerUp"
```

to

```
eventType = "mouseover touchend MSPointerUp"
```

So it react on `mouseover` and the click event can be used for linking.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(".flex-control-nav li").hover(function() { 
         $(this).parent().parent().flexslider($(this).index());
    });
```

Slide changes only when you hover over list items not the navigation buttons.

Answer (score 0):

I needed you to be able to click the link in the controlnav to go to an article. I built off of frendo's answer and added this to my flexslider function:

```
        start: function (slider) {
        $('.top-btns a').mouseover(function () {
            $('#home-banner').flexslider($(this).index());
        });
```

Then, elsewhere in your javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.top-btns a').click(function () {
        window.location.href = $(this).attr('href');
    });
});
```

You'll need to change ".top-btns a" to reference your controlnav and "#home-banner" to the flexslider you're wanting to change.  Then, I have the href of each link in the controlnav be the page you want the user to navigate to.

Answer (score 0):

this is a simple way to resolve this:

```
jQuery('.flex-control-nav li').on('mouseenter', function () {
    $(this).trigger('click');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the answers helped me a lot, I wasn't able to use the answers, because the project I'am working on doesn't allow me to change the flexslider script or the initialization script.

The solution below allows you to have manualControl list elements in the flexslider, enabeling you to have custom links in in it. 
When you hover, it changes the slide, if you click it will go to the page.

```
//Define the navigation elements of the manualControls flexslider
            var $sb = $('.product-slider-nav li a');

//Flexslider click hover handler
            function FlexHoverHandler(event) {
                $element = $(this);
                if (event.data.event == 'mouseover') {
                    $element.trigger('click');
                }
                if (event.data.event == 'mouseup') {
                    window.location.href = $element.attr('href');
                }
            }

//Bind mouseover and mouseup 
            $sb.on('mouseover', {event: 'mouseover'}, FlexHoverHandler);
            $sb.on('mouseup', {event: 'mouseup'}, FlexHoverHandler);
```